# Searching for keywords with javascript method search();

Tags: javascript, html

I have this program where the user can input text and then click a button to that searches for keywords in the users input if a key word is found it alert found! but if didn't work it alerts: not found! I tried something like this:

```
  function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById('demo'); 
  var n = str.search("wow");

  if (n = true){
      alert("found");
  } else {
      alert("not found");
  }
```

But this didn't work. Whenever I search for something it gives me this: str.search is not a function.

Here is my full code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById('demo'); 
  var n = str.search("wow");

  if (n = true){
      alert("found");
  } else {
      alert("not found");
  }
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

Comment: `if (n = true){` you probably want a comparison, not an assignment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to check the `value` of the input, not the input itself.
2. It's better to use `includes` here instead of `search`.
3. `=` is assignment; `==` and `===` are for comparison. Moreover, comparing boolean values is nearly always redundant.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById('demo').value;
  var n = str.includes("wow");
  if (n) {
    alert("found");
  } else {
    alert("not found");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` in fact is not a string it's a `HTML element`

```
var str = document.getElementById('demo');
```

If you want to use `str.search` you have to work with regular expressions, I advise using the built in function `includes` for this kind of feature